# Apple watch - open maps programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch

Is it possible to open navigation programmatically? Task: add button "navigate". After click native navigation should open map with specific point to navigate to. In iPhone you can use:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:...];
```

How about Apple watch?

Comment: Do you mean other map: Google Maps  etc?

Comment: Edited. Now should be cleaner. Button should open apple maps navigation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In watchOS 1 there isn't a way to open Maps from a button press. If you display a `WKInterfaceMap` of the location in your app, however, tapping it will opens the Maps app centred on the location your map was displaying.

Comment: It's kinda sucks. One more question - will maps be navigate to my pin place or tap location? How about WatchOS 2? Is it possible there?